# Inno setup: How do I hide the the Add/Remove entry in the control panel?

Tags: inno-setup

I have created an install using Inno Setup.

I'm using Uninstallable=true and everything is fine but I need to get rid of the entry in the Add/remote programs applet.

Is there a magic setting that I don't know about?

Thanks

Comment: Un-uninstallable programs are evil... Any reason you're forcing your app to stick around forever?

Comment: Well, 'Uninstallable' should be **false** to not to have add/remove entries.

Comment: I still need the uninstall program to be build, just the add/remove entry hidden or deleted.  It's a network security product so the program can only be removed via a central console.

Comment: If it's a security product, then you should not rely on the absence of an entry in Add/Remove programs. If an user doesn't have admin rights, he can for example delete the folder in Program Files that contains the application. If he doesn't have admin rights, he can't uninstall it anyway.

Comment: @Iunknown - Didn't quite understand the design, but you can delete the entry for the ARP from within the [Run] section which is run after the program is installed via a little utility or perhaps a .reg file.

Comment: I tend to agree, but customers asked for me to remove it from the Add/Report programs.  I can block the actual uninstall with no trouble, but I guess they don't want the question to come up.

Comment: Thanks Sertac,  I hadn't considered using a reg file, but that should work.  So I'm guessing that there isn't anything built into InnoSetup.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `CreateUninstallRegKey` directive.